# perl - Hash in hash - how are elements stored?

Tags: perl

I am a newbie to perl programming and having tough time to adapt from C to perl. Would greatly appreciate your help.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %tgs;
$tgs{"0"}{"1"} = 01;
$tgs{"0"}{"2"} = 02;
$tgs{"0"}{"3"} = 03;
$tgs{"1"}{"1"} = 11;
$tgs{"1"}{"2"} = 12;
$tgs{"1"}{"3"} = 13;
$tgs{"2"}{"1"} = 21;
$tgs{"2"}{"2"} = 22;
$tgs{"2"}{"3"} = 23;


print Dumper(\%tgs);
exit(0);
```

o/p is

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => {
                   '1' => 11,
                   '3' => 13,
                   '2' => 12
                 },
          '0' => {
                   '1' => 1,
                   '3' => 3,
                   '2' => 2
                 },
          '2' => {
                   '1' => 21,
                   '3' => 23,
                   '2' => 22
                 }
        };
```

I have entered the hash values in the order of 1,2,3. But when i print the order is first 1 then 0 and then 2. Why is it happenning like this? Is there any way i can controle this? I need to control it because i will read this data in a `foreach` loop by assuming it is of the order 0 1 2 3...

Comment: Hash tables don't remember the order that the items were added, they're just a mapping from keys to values.

Comment: if you care about order, use arrays, not hashes.

Comment: This perlfaq might help: [How can I make my hash remember the order I put elements into it?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-make-my-hash-remember-the-order-I-put-elements-into-it-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl doesn't guarantee anything about the order of the keys in a hash.  If you must loop over the elements in a specific order, you can do:

```
for (sort keys %myhash) {
    print Dumper($tgs{$_});
}
```

Or if the keys aren't easily sorted, you may need to use an array with a mapping:

```
my %tgs;
$tgs{"0"}{"1"} = 01;
$tgs{"0"}{"2"} = 02;
$tgs{"0"}{"3"} = 03;
$tgs{"1"}{"1"} = 11;
$tgs{"1"}{"2"} = 12;
$tgs{"1"}{"3"} = 13;
$tgs{"2"}{"1"} = 21;
$tgs{"2"}{"2"} = 22;
$tgs{"2"}{"3"} = 23;

my @tag_keys = qw(1 2 3);
```

And then use:

```
foreach (@tag_keys) {
    print Dumper($tgs{$_});
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is informative. For my prblm, i used 'for' instead of "foreach" like $tgs{i}{j}. :) To use arrays and hashes for my actual task i would need more practice. Thanks for the solution though

Comment: in Perl, `for` and `foreach` are interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

Hashes are unordered, as you have discovered.  If you're familiar with "hash tables" in C, it's essentially the same thing - the keys are passed through a hashing function and the hash keys ended up sorted by the resulting hashes.  And if the hashing function is any good (it is), that order is effectively random.  Additionally, recent versions of Perl have implemented randomization functions which will cause the order of the hash keys to be different each time your program runs.  So you really, *really* can't count on hash keys having any particular order.

Or at least you can't... by default.

There's long been a desire for hashes which remember the order that keys were inserted, so someone invented [Tie::IxHash](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie%3a%3aIxHash), which acts just like a regular hash, except that it also attaches a little metadata to each key to indicate their order.